# Confluent kafka Python client Avro producer.producer() executes without error but no data in topic

Tags: kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

My producer isnt throwing any errors but data is not being sent to the destination topic. Can you recommend any techniques to debug this situation.

I have call to a Confluent Python Avro Producer inside a synchronous loop to send data to a topic like so:

```
self.producer.produce(topic=test2, value=msg_dict)
```

After this call I have a piece of code like so to flush the queue:

```
num_messages_in_queue = self.producer.flush(timeout = 2.0)
print(f"flushed {num_messages_in_queue} messages from producer queue in iteration {num_iterations} ")
```

this executes without any error. But also there is no callback fired after this code executes. My producer is initiated as follows:

```
 def __init__(self,broker_url=None,topic=None,schema_registry_url=None,schema_path=None):
  try:
    with open(schema_path, 'r') as content_file:
      schema = avro.loads(content_file.read())
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error when trying to read avro schema file : {schema_path}")

  self.conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': broker_url,
    'on_delivery': self.delivery_report,
    'schema.registry.url': schema_registry_url,
    'acks': -1, #This guarantees that the record will not be lost as long as at least one in-sync replica remains alive. 
    'enable.idempotence': False, #
    "error_cb":self.error_cb
  }
  self.topic = topic
  self.schema_path = schema_path
  self.producer = AvroProducer(self.conf,default_key_schema=schema, default_value_schema=schema)
```

My callback method is as follows:

```
def delivery_report(self, err, msg):
    print(f"began delivery_report")
    if err is None:
        print(f"delivery_report --> Delivered msg.value = {msg.value()} to topic= {msg.topic()} offset = {msg.offset} without err.")
    else:
        print(f"conf_worker AvroProducer failed to deliver message {msg.value()} to topic {self.topic}. got error= {err}")
```

After this code is executed, I look at my topic on the schema registry container like so:

```
docker exec schema_registry_container kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --topic test2 --from-beginning
```

I see this output:

> > [2020-04-03 15:48:38,064] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean 
> >     (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:38,742] 
> >     INFO ConsumerConfig values: 
> >           auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
> >           auto.offset.reset = earliest
> >           bootstrap.servers = [kafka:29092]
> >           check.crcs = true
> >           client.dns.lookup = default
> >           client.id = 
> >           connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
> >           default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
> >           enable.auto.commit = false
> >           exclude.internal.topics = true
> >           fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
> >           fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
> >           fetch.min.bytes = 1
> >           group.id = console-consumer-49056
> >           heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
> >           interceptor.classes = []
> >           internal.leave.group.on.close = true
> >           isolation.level = read_uncommitted
> >           key.deserializer = class >> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
> >            max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
> >            max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
> >            max.poll.records = 500
> >            metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
> >            metric.reporters = []
> >            metrics.num.samples = 2
> >            metrics.recording.level = INFO
> >            metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
> >            partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
> >            receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
> >            reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
> >           reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
> >            request.timeout.ms = 30000
> >            retry.backoff.ms = 100
> >            sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
> >            sasl.jaas.config = null
> >            sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
> >            sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
> >            sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
> >            sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
> >            sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
> >            sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
> >            sasl.login.class = null
> >            sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
> >            sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
> >            sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
> >            sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
> >            sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
> >            security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
> >            send.buffer.bytes = 131072
> >            session.timeout.ms = 10000
> >            ssl.cipher.suites = null
> >            ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
> >            ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
> >            ssl.key.password = null
> >            ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
> >            ssl.keystore.location = null
> >            ssl.keystore.password = null
> >            ssl.keystore.type = JKS
> >            ssl.protocol = TLS
> >            ssl.provider = null
> >            ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
> >            ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
> >            ssl.truststore.location = null
> >            ssl.truststore.password = null
> >            ssl.truststore.type = JKS
> >            value.deserializer = class >>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
> >      (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:38,887] INFO Kafka version : 2.1.0-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:38,887] INFO Kafka commitId : bda8715f42a1a3db (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:39,221] INFO Cluster ID: KHKziPBvRKiozobbwvP1Fw (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:39,224] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-49056] Discovered group coordinator kafka:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:39,231] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-49056] Revoking previously assigned partitions [] 
> >     (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:39,231] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-49056] (Re-)joining group >(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:42,264] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-49056] Successfully joined group with generation 1 
> >     (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:42,267] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-49056] Setting newly assigned partitions [test2-0] >(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
> >     [2020-04-03 15:48:42,293] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-49056] Resetting offset for partition test2-0 to offset 0. >(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is so trivial that its embarassing!
But it does point to the fact that in a multilayered infrastructure, a single value incorrectly set, can result in a silent failure which can be very tedious to track down.

So the issue came from incorrect param setting my in my docker-compose.yml file, where the env variable for broker_url was not set.
The application code needed this variable to reference the kafka broker. 
However there was no exception thrown for this missing param and it was silently failing.